# What version of C does Python take?

Tags: python, python-2.7

From what I understand, the canonical version of Python is written in C89. I'm interested in maybe writing some C based extension to Python later on, but I'm a bit confused as to what version of C I should use (couldn't find on Python documentation). Since Python is in C89, should I code in C89 or would C11 code work as well?

Comment: Anything that your target compilers support should be fine as far as I know ...

Comment: Can you unpack that a bit further?

Comment: From the [Python devguide](http://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#build-dependencies): *if you get compile errors with a C89 or C99-compliant compiler, please open a bug report.* But that applies to the Python *core* **only**.

Comment: It's the output format that matters in this case. `C89` and `C99` both compile to the same format on your computer: you can even link C code to other languages (Java, Haskell), and have it work. Why shouldn't C to C work as well?

Comment: The requirements for extensions are much more relaxed. There are plenty of extensions written in C++ for example.

Comment: Thank you all, clears it up for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C as a language has seen only relatively minor evolution since C89. It is very easy to code in the intersection of C89, C99 and C11, and this is what I would recommend you do (not so much for interfacing with Python, which is more at the ABI level, but as general source-level best practice).

Off the top of my head, by limiting yourself to C89, you lose the `for (int i=0;…)` syntax, variable length arrays, and complex numbers.

By writing for C99 you lose the ability to declare variables with the implicit type `int` that C89 allowed. It was never a good idea.

C11 makes it clear that some constructs are forbidden when it was ambiguous in previous standards: `INT_MIN % (-1)`, `(0,i++,j) + (0,j++,i)`([discussion](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/04/13/Making-oughts-from-ises); see comments).

The most useful addition introduced in C99 may have been C++-style `//` comments. Bu tmost compilers already accepted those as an extension even before C99 was published, so there is no reason to refrain form using them in 2013.

Comment: On a related note, should I stick with C11 for everything C related?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian If you are programming with threads, definitely. Otherwise, there is little C11 has to offer over C99.